# Sencha touch 2 - Displaying a nested Model in a DataView

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a model that represents a user. The user has some personal fields (name, family) and another Model as hasMany (his phones, for example).

Something like that:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['ID', 'Name', 'Family'],
        hasMany: { model: 'MyApp.model.Phone', name: 'Phones', associationKey: 'phones' }
   }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Phone', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['ID', 'Phone', 'Type']
   }
});
```

Now, I'd like to load it to a dataview (which I did successfully) and would like to show the user info, then the list of the phones that belong to him and when a user taps a phone - to show it using a layout (or message, or anything - the point is to get it's ID)

The problem is that when I use itemtap it gets me the whole record, including the user info and all the phones - so I can't really know what phone was tapped.

To show the user info I just use the itemTpl that shows the info and then lists all the phones.

So - how can I know what phone was tapped?

Thanks!
Roman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clean way to do this, unless you directly bind the `phones` (`userRecord.phones()`) store to the dataview. Instead, you will need to get he target of the `itemtap` event and check what element that is.

```
itemtap: function(me, index, target, record, e) {
    var el = Ext.get(e.target);
    alert(el.dom.innerHTML);
}
```

Full example:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
            fullscreen: true,
            store: {
                fields: ['name'],
                data: [
                    { name: 'one' },
                    { name: 'two' }
                ]
            },
            itemTpl: '{name} <span>tap me</span>',
            listeners: {
                itemtap: function(me, index, target, record, e) {
                    var el = Ext.get(e.target);
                    alert(el.dom.innerHTML);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I did eventually :) Thanks.

Comment: I've added a data attribute to each div - such that when I got the DOM object - I could know what record what chosen